# Interesting trouble with getlistitems not returning list items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, spservices

I'm a bit new to spservices, and I hope I'm not asking a question that's already been answered. I've checked and haven't been able to find one like it.
I'm using GetListItems to retrieve url's and titles stored in a list. No problems understanding the logic, and it **should** work. Right now I'm retrieving items and just displaying them in a temporary table.

It works perfectly in a little html page that I've created that references the js files, jquery, etc.

But,

When I set a Content Editor Web Part to point to the html file (using the Content Link), the javascript doesn't work, (or something), and the items aren't displayed. I found out where exactly it stopped working:

```
 $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         alert("When it's in the Content Editor Web Part, this gets called");
                        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
         alert("but this does not");
                            var hyperlink = ($(this).attr("ows_Hyperlink")).split(",");
                            var url = hyperlink[0];
                            var description = hyperlink[1];


                            AddRowToTable(url,description);

                        });                
                    }
        });
```

As I said before, this code works perfectly when going to the physical address of the html page. It grabs the list items and displays the correct things. The problems occur when I reference, through the Content Link, the html page in the Content Editor Web Part.
If anyone has insight on this, it would be most welcome.
Thanks, AA

Comment: If the first alert is displayed, but the second isn't, then it suggest that the query work, but doesn't return any rows. What's in xData.responseXML?

Comment: I put this in: alert(xData.responseXML); and it gives me this: [object XMLDocument]

Comment: Try `alert(xData.response.XML.xml);` or `console.log(xData.response.XML.xml);` and use Developer Tools (F12)

Comment: It says that the list doesn't exist. I don't understand. Does it being in a CEWP mess with where it looks?

Comment: Not if it's on the same Site as where you tried with html page. Have you checked your variables (list, query, ...)?

Comment: I've found out what happened. I was trying to access the root vti_bin, but it was accessing the sub-site vti_bin for Lists.asmx. How can I set it to not look in the sub-site vti_bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments to the question you mention that you found that the page is in a subsite and the list you want is at the root site.

To change where it looks for the list you can specify a webURL property:

```
 $().SPServices({ 
            operation: method, 
            async: false, 
            webURL: 'http://sharepoint/',
            listName: list, 
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead, 
              CAMLQuery: query, 
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                        var hyperlink = ($(this).attr("ows_Hyperlink")).split(","); 
                        var url = hyperlink[0]; 
                        var description = hyperlink[1]; 


                        AddRowToTable(url,description); 

                    });                 
                } 
    });
```